# Validate uploaded file type using Java script

Tags: javascript, validation, jsp

I take a file via a form , and ask to validate its type. but it sounds the java script doesn't work or the invoke is not seen ?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Upload2.jsp"
 method="post" onsubmit="javascript:return validate();">
    <td><b>Choose txt file To Upload:</b></td>
    <td><input name="file" type="file"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Upload File" ></td>
</form>
```

And here's the script:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function validate(){
        if(document.form.file.value == "" ) {
            alert("Enter course code !");
            return false;}

        else {
            var value = document.form.file.value;
            var ext = value.substr(dot, value.length);
            //ext = value.slice(file.indexOf(".")).toLowerCase();
            if ( ext=="txt" ) {
                return true; }
            else{
                alert("choose a .txt file");
                return false;}
            }
       }
</script>
```

And this is the form..
tho i am not sure of my script correctness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture what's after the last period in a string using:

```
ext = value.split(".").pop();
```

---

You take your String `value` split it into an array:

```
var myValue = "some.thing.ext";

var myArray = myValue.split(".");
```

now myArray is:

```
["some", "thing", "ext"];
```

You can now pop the last value from the array using `.pop()`.

```
var ext = myArray.pop();
```

now

```
ext === "ext";
myArray === ["some", "thing"]
```

---

in context:

```
function validate(){
    if(document.form.file.value == "" ) {
        alert("Enter course code !");
        return false;}

    else {
        var value = document.form.file.value,
            ext = value.split(".").pop();
        if ( ext == "txt" ) {
            return true; }
        else{
            alert("choose a .txt file");
            return false;}
        }
   }
```

If you change your onsubmit to:

```
onsubmit="javascript:return validate(this);"
```

Then you will get the form element as first argument in value:

```
function validate(form){
    var value = form.file.value,
        ext = value.split(".").pop();

    if( !value ) {
        alert("Enter course code !");
    }
    else if ( ext !== "txt" ) {
        alert("choose a .txt file");
    }

    return ( ext === "txt" );
}
```

---

**NOTE:**

Never use javaScript as your only validation. Use some sort of server-site language to determinate if the validation is passed.

Use JS to make i more slick for the user to operate on your site.

Comment: @ Andreas AL:
I added the validate function you wrote, but when i do run the project. it is like i have no "on submit=javascript return: validate();" and immediately goes to the action page..
What do you mean with "server-side language to determine if the validation is passed"? Do you mean inside my (Upload2.jsp) i need to validate the type?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for validating the type of file uploaded and limiting its  size is

```
var ext = $('#uploadFeedback').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
    alert('invalid extension!');
}
```

Above for file type validation.

```
var uploadedFile = document.getElementById('uploadFeedback');      
var fileSize = uploadedFile.files[0].size;
```

Above for file size validation